# What to use for advanced kiosk mode that starts other programs with minimal Ui

Tags: x11, raspberry-pi, raspbian, x-server, kiosk

**What I want:**

I want a kisok mode application that starts/runs a shell script that opens a vnc viewer. Also it needed to disable all key funktions like alt + f4 or alt + tab etc. Thats it.

**What I found:**

I found many tutorials to only start chromium with a X server but with this setup I cant start a vnc client. So later I found [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) and it sems that it has everything I need. nearly all hotkeys are not avaible on a basic X server.

**What I did:**

I created a [nw.js](https://nwjs.io/) site/application with a button inside that opens [ssvnc/vncviewer](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html)/[xthightvncviewer](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/xtightvncviewer). I set the application to kiosk mode and fullscreen mode. In my first test it has opened in kiosk mode and a button press later the vnc Viewer ask me for a password and I was connected to another pc.

**The Problem:**

Now my second test was to start my pie in console only and try my application with "startx myapp". The first thing I noticed was that the application is like 600x800 big and not Fullscreen. After a button press, the vnc Viewer opens but I cant write anything in the Password TextBox. And because the Viewer window has no close button I was stuck there. In a later test the button opend ssvnc Client and in this application I can press every button, mark every Checkbox and also switch every menu but I cant still excess the text boxes (the same thing with xtightvncviewer).

**The Question:**

How can I acces the textboxes on programs that are opened as second program on a basic X server?

Optional: Do you know another vnc viewer that can be opened via console? Maybe the ones I used dont work for this.

Optional²: Or does a window manager exits that acts like a kiosk mode except that you can move windows and close them and Nothing more?

Comment: Look at the ratpoison window manager

Comment: But can I use a mouse in ratpoison?

Comment: Sorry, I picked the wrong window manager from memory. I meant matchbox

Comment: Ok that matchbox thing is very good. looks like a kiosk mode and my application Looks like it should. I now just need to get to start with my script when my pie boots :) One more thing, when I try Fullscreen with the vncviewer (Fullscreen, not the maximised window) the vnc window disappears, but is still open somewhere.

Comment: Followwed half of [this tutorial for autostart](https://maker-tutorials.com/autostart-midori-browser-vollbild-kiosk-mode-via-konsole-ohne-desktop/). Now all the parts are working except a few minor bug :) feel free to make an answere to use matchbox so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Matchbox](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/matchbox-window-manager/) window manager is normally a good start for this sort of project.

It displays a single application at a time full screen.

Comment: Do you know if matchbox has any Hotkeys that I should disable?